# Errors in Unity console but not in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, .net-framework-version

I recently upgraded my Unity C# project's .NET version from 3.5 to 4.5.2. Everything compiles beautifully in my Visual Studio project, but i have errors in my Unity Console which are not showing in VS and these errors are prohibiting me from running my project. It seems as though my project didn't *actually* upgrade to 4.5.2, is there any way to solve this?

[image]

EDIT: i've tried upgrading unity's framework version by going into Edit -> Project Settings -> Player -> Configuration -> Scripting Runtime Version and changing that value to `.NET 4.x Equivalent` but it changed nothing

Comment: Visual Studio uses latest C# compiler, while Unity, though upgraded, should not use the same yet. So post what exactly errors you got and maybe we can suggest workarounds.

Comment: @LexLi i just added a picture of my errors. it's basically not recognizing the mysql dll that i've added

Comment: Have you added the dll reference to your solution in visual studio?

Comment: @DanielLoudon yup, `MySql.Data.dll` is in my references, and everything compiles fine in visual studio

Comment: I'm not experienced with unity, just visual studio sorry

Comment: Where did you put the ``MySql.Data.dll``? Adding it to Visual Studio's references will do nothing to Unity's ability to find the dll.

Comment: @AnLog yeah i added it to my project's references in Visual Studio, is there a place in Unity where i'm supposed to add the .dll reference?

Comment: _Unity3D doesn't do .dll references._ The .dll file itself needs to be your asset files. https://answers.unity.com/questions/458300/how-to-use-a-external-dll.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a copy of the MySql.Data.dll in your Assets folder?  References in Unity work differently than in Visual Studio.  You add a reference in Unity by dropping the .dll into the Assets folder (preferably in a directory that makes sense, not at the root so that it is easy to find and doesn't clutter the root).  You should always get your code working in Unity first and then compile in Visual Studio, not the other way around.